# unable to retrieve value from edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi I am trying to retrieve certain values from my edit text.

firstly, when I did not enter anything, i did a toast to notify me that there is no text input and it works!

then when I enter text and this time, the toasts appear again! when there is text input..

the codes to display toast / retrieve text:

```
public class ResetPassword extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PASS = "pass";

    String enteredPassword;
    String changedPass;
    String currentPass;
    //String password;

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    //private static String url_member_login = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_login.php";
    private static String url_login = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/change_password.php";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.password);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        ImageButton home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_home);
        home.setOnClickListener(this);


        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                if (currentPass != null && changedPass != null)
                {
                   new ResetPass().execute();
                }     
                else
                {
                    /** A TEMPORARY DISPLAY FROM CUSTOM TOAST **/
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,
                                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

                    TextView text1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_engRecords);
                    TextView text2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_chiRecords);

                    text1.setText("Feature is temporarily unavailable");
                    text2.setText("Unable to update ");

                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setView(layout);
                    toast.show();               

                }

                }});

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */

    class ResetPass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // check json success tag
            try {
                // Building Parameters

                   EditText currentPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_current);
                    currentPass = currentPassword.getText().toString();

                    EditText newPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_new);
                    changedPass = newPassword.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PASSWORD, changedPass));

                // sending modified data through http request
                // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login,
                        "GET", params);

                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't do things like the following... `EditText currentPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_current);` within the `doInBackground(...)` method of `AsyncTask`. Use the `onPreExecute()` method of `AysncTask` to access UI elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access UI elements from Background thread means from doInBackground.you must pass EditText values to doInBackground as parameter as:

First add EditText vlaues in an ArrayList as:

```
public static List<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    arrlist.add(currentPassword.getText().toString());
    arrlist.add(newPassword.getText().toString());
```

Now pass this List to AsyncTask as :

```
new ResetPass().execute(arrlist);
```

Change your AsyncTask class as :

```
 class ResetPass extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, String, String> {

        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... args) {

                    // check json success tag
                  try {
                       // Building Parameters
                      ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                      result = passing[0]; //get passed arraylist
                      currentPass = result.get(0); // get old pass from ArrayList
                      changedPass = result.get(1);// get new pass from ArrayList
                      //...your code here
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the onPreExecute() routine to access the UI elements, but this method is probably better.  Also I'd strongly advise you to make sure currentPass & changedPass are null when you need them to be.  If you don't re-nullify them after the user runs this asynchronous task once, they won't be able to run it again because the variables will still store old values.

Comment: then how ca u access currentPass & changedPass in doInBackground ?i think will we need to use some extra class level static variables for getting  currentPass & changedPass values in `doInBackground` and this is not best practice to use more variables or static variables in Application.

Comment: Well it depends on what you're looking to do.  If you don't need to know their values but just need to know they're set, then you can access them in onPreExecute() and decide whether or not to continue there.  It'll be difficult to pass along their values to the doInBackground() method unless we use your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did not know I couldn't access UI elements in the background thread. I have re-written my codes a little and now it works perfectly. thank you all! :)

Comment: @Jolene You can access the UI elements in the doInBackground() method.. You can do like this while having your edittext references initialized in the onCreate().                                currentPass = currentPassword.getText().toString();
changedPass = newPassword.getText().toString();